# Parse.com PHP SDK case insensitive search query

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse and I'm not a very well-experienced PHP developer.

I'm trying to run a search query using Parse.com PHP SDK on _User class.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $query = new ParseQuery('_User');
$query->startsWith("s_first_name", $user);
$results = $query->find();
foreach ($results as $result) { ?>
        <?php echo $result->get('s_first_name')." ".$result->get('s_last_name'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

It works but it's case sensitive. Also I don't think the "startsWith" is the best function to use since I needed something similar to "contains" in MYSQL.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: isnt parse closed?

Comment: @dynamic just the hosting services, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to fix this using PHP so I used their Javascript SDK instead with toUpperCase() and toLowerCase() functions.

```
function capitalize(str) {
    var pieces = str.split(" ");
    for ( var i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++ ) {
        var j = pieces[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        pieces[i] = j + pieces[i].substr(1);
    }
    return pieces.join(" ");
}

//get search term from php
var searhTerm = <?php echo json_encode($user); ?>;

//capitalize keyword for accurate results
var keyword = ".*"+capitalize(searhTerm);+".*";
//start search
var searchUser = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
//queries
var query1 = new Parse.Query(searchUser);
query1.matches("s_first_name", keyword.toLowerCase());
query1.equalTo("type", "seaman");
.
.
.
//do query find
```